# Suppose "value" is any integer: is value++ the direct equivalent to value = value + 1;?

Tags: java, expression, operands

I understand that the values of the two would be the same (say 3 to 4). However, does the computer see the two as the same, and would they both be considered expressions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Yes to both, except that `(value++)` evaluates to the old value, whereas `(value = value + 1)` evaluates to the new value.
The direct equivalent of `(value = value + 1)` within an expression is `(++value)`.

Note that neither of them are thread-safe.

For added fun, here are two more equivalent options:

```
value += 1;
value -= -1;
```

Comment: True as long as `value` is a simple variable or simple array element reference.  If it's something like `method(args).field`, where `method(args)` returns an object reference, then `++method(args).field` calls the method once, while `method(args).field = method(args).field + 1` calls it twice.

Comment: This is the only answer that really distinguishes between the values of the expressions themselves versus the number that resides within `value` after evaluating either expression.  The values of the expressions differ, though `value` will hold the same number after either expression is evaluated (assuming the target has no side effects, as @ajb pointed out).

Answer (score 2):

That's incorrect. Rather, ++value is the same as value=value+1.

++Value is a pre-increment. Value++ is a post-increment.

'Post' means after - that is, the increment is done after the variable is read. 'Pre' means before - so the variable value is incremented first, then used in the expression.

For example:

```
int i, x;

i = 2;
x = ++i;
// now i = 3, x = 3

i = 2;
x = i++; 
// now i = 3, x = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

No, my friend ++value is equivalent to value=value+1 as it is changing the new value preincrement operator
and value++ is changing the old value which is kept in the memory i.e. post incrementing it